# Understanding the exact meaning of the "void" Keyword in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

As explained, for example, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxky5d0w.aspx), there are 3 main uses for the void keyword (more experienced C/C++ programmers can skip to the 4th use):

**1) As a return type for function that doesn't return anything**. This
    will cause a code sample like this:

```
void foo();
int i = foo();
```

to generate a compiler error.

**2) As the only parameter in a function's parameter list**. AFAIK, an empty function's parameter list is exactly the same to the compiler and therefore the following 2 lines are identical in meaning:
(**edit:** it is only true in c++. The comments show the difference in c).

```
int foo();
int foo(void);
```

**3) void* is a special type of generic pointer**- it can point to any variable that is not declared with the const or volatile keyword, convert to/from any type of data pointer, and point to all non-member functions. In addition, it cannot be dereferenced. I will not give examples.

There is also a 4th use that I don't fully understand:

**4) In conditional compilation** it is often used in the expression (void)0 as following:

```
// procedure that actually prints error message 
void _assert(char* file, int line, char* test); 
#ifdef NDEBUG 
#define assert(e) ((void)0) 
#else
#define assert(e)     \
((e) ? (void)0 :   \
__assert(__FILE__, __LINE__, #e)) 
#endif
```

I'm trying to understand the behavior of this expression through experiments. All the following are valid (compile well):

```
int foo(); // some function declaration
int (*fooPtr)(); // function pointer
void(foo);
void(fooPtr);
void(0);
(void)0;
void('a');
void("blabla");
exampleClass e; //some class named exampleClass with a default ctor
void(e);
static_cast<void>(e);
```

but these are not:

```
void(0) // no semicolon
int i = void(0);
```

Can I conclude from this that "void" **(in the context of the 4th use)** is simply a special type that any type can cast to it  (whether it is c-style or cpp-style), and it can never be used as an lvalue or rvalue?

Comment: **2** is only true about C++, in C an empty function's parameter list means the function takes any number of unspecified arguments.

Comment: You can also return an expression that evaluates to `void` from a function whose return type is `void`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: You can do that in C++, but not in C.  In C, a void function can only have a bare `return;`.  (C99 6.8.6.4p1.)

Comment: Are you sure that `void(e);` compiles in C++?

Comment: The answer to your final question is no:  `void()` creates an rvalue of type `void`.

Comment: @KeithThompson that's why I hate questions about "the C/C++ language."

Comment: [I don't get it](http://www.qubik.com/zr/)

Comment: @KerrekSB: `void(e)` == `(void)e` == `static_cast<void>(e)`. It is a common idiom for expressing that a variable is deliberately not used.

Comment: I don't think it's worthwhile to try to understand what `void` by itself means.  It is just a keyword that means different things in different contexts.  Similarly the keyword `static` means like 8 different things in C++ and I don't think you will find a single definition that fully explains it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I conclude from this that "void" (in the context of the 4th use) is simply a special type that any type can cast to it (whether it is c-style or cpp-style), and it can never be used as an lvalue or rvalue?

James McNellis pointed out in [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024790/understanding-the-exact-meaning-of-the-void-keyword-in-c-c/8024840#comment9823193_8024840) that `void` can be used as an rvalue via the expression `void()`.

He quoted this from the current C++ standard:

> **C++11 §5.2.3/2:**
> “The expression `T()`, where `T` is a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) `void` type, creates a prvalue of the specified type, which is value-initialized (no initialization is done for the `void()` case).”

This makes it possible to write code like …

```
template< class T >
T foo() { return T(); }
```

and use `foo<void>()` (most likely from other templated code, I would imagine).

Formally `void` is just an incomplete type that *can never be completed*.

Answer (score 7):

As for your **2)**, in C these:

```
int foo();
int foo(void);
```

are *not* equivalent.

The first is an old-style declaration (still supported in the latest C standard) that says `foo` takes a fixed *but unspecified* number and type of argument(s).  A call like `foo(42)` doesn't require a diagnostic, but its behavior is undefined unless the *definition* of `foo` says it has a single `int` parameter.

The second says specifically that `foo` takes no arguments, and `foo(42)` requires a diagnostic.  The second declaration is a prototype; the first is not.  The `(void)` syntax was added because some special syntax was needed to be able to declare a parameterless function without writing something that looks like an old-style declaration.

In new C code, you should *always* use prototypes.  Old-style declarations are kept in the language only to support old code.

C++ dropped old-style declarations.  In C++, the two declarations of `foo` *are* equivalent; the `int foo(void)` form is supported only for compatibility with C.

Your case **4)** really has nothing directly to do with conditional compilation.  Casting an expression to `void` is a way of evaluating the expression and explicitly discarding its value.  It's often used to inhibit warnings.  For example, if `foo()` returns an `int` result, then

```
foo();
```

as a standalone statement might trigger a warning that you're discarding the result, but

```
(void)foo();
```

probably tells the compiler that you intended to do so.

`void` is an incomplete type that cannot be completed.  That means that an expression of type `void` can *only* be used in a context that doesn't expect a value.  And you're right, an expression of type `void` cannot be used as an lvalue or rvalue.  **EDIT**: Except in the case Alf described, and only in C++.

Comment: int foo() and int foo(void) are equivalent in C++, not in C.

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti: I believe that's exactly what I said.

Comment: Using casts to `void` to inhibit warnings is perverse, but it's rather useful when you want to *create* errors if somebody tries to use the value of a function-like macro that's intended not to return a value.

Answer (score 4):

Void is a type with no values.  Since it has no values, expressions of type `void` can only be used for their side effects.  Here are some corrections:

**#1** Yes.

**#2** As mentioned, is correct in C++ but incorrect in C.

```
int foo(); // In C, this is an "old-style" prototype
           // which doesn't declare its parameters

// Definition for the above function: valid in C, not valid in C++
int foo(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
```

**#3** `void*` is a special type of generic pointer: Not quite.  It is not portable to cast a function pointer to `void*` and back again.

```
void func(void);
void *x = func;
void (*f)(void) = func; // NOT portable
```

However, you can cast any function pointer to any other function pointer type in C, and back again, without worrying about portability.

**#4** Also used to explicitly indicate to the compiler that a value is not needed.

```
// Generates "unused parameter warning"
int func(int x)
{
    return 3;
}

// Does not generate any warnings
int func(int x)
{
    (void) x;
    return 3;
}
```

I recommend always turning unused parameter warnings on for your projects, because they often let you catch simple typos.

Answer (score 2):

`void` is always an *incomplete* type, which means you can never instantiate any object of type `void`. <s>Consequently there can't be *any* values of this type, neither L nor R.</s> There can't be any lvalue of this type, though `void()` is an (p)rvalue. [Thanks to @James!]

For `void*`, three common uses come to mind: 1) it's big enough to hold any object pointer. 2) dynamic-cast to void pointer yields a pointer to the most derived type. 3) it's the type of raw memory pointers, i.e. the result type of `std::malloc()` and `::operator new()`, the argument type of `std::free()` and `::operator delete()`, and of placement-new. It shouldn't be used for anything else in strict C++, though it's also used in the latter role as the buffer argument for `fread` and `fwrite` in the C library.

Comment: `void()` creates an rvalue of type `void` (or, in C++11, a prvalue).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: How can you have a value of an incomplete type?

Comment: C++11 §5.2.3/2:  "The expression `T()`, where `T` is a _simple-type-specifier_ or _typename-specifier_ for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates a prvalue of the specified type, which is value-initialized (no initialization is done for the `void()` case)."